# Compiler doesn't show a warning if empty function is not marked as pure

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, compiler, solidity-0.5.x

When compiling a function without marking its state mutability as `pure`, the compiler shows the following warning:

```
Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
```

For example:

```
contract MyContract {
    function foo() public {
        1 + 2;
    }
}
```

As expected, the compiler shows

```
    Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
        function foo() public {
        ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

The compiler doesn't show the warning if the function's body is empty. For example:

```
contract MyContract {
    function foo() public {
    }
}
```

Here the compiler does not show a warning as expected. Why is that?

The versions used while testing was `0.5.8` and `0.8.7`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't show any warning for your empty functions because it can't know your intent. If you add a return to it this should be different.

An empty function doesn't interact with any state nor perform any calculations so that's why the compiler doesn't suggest any specific state mutability restriction like `pure` or `view`

Comment: I don't understand. That's exactly why I expect it to how a warning. Looking at the [doc's cheatsheet](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/cheatsheet.html#modifiers), the `pure` modifier disallows modification or access of state. An empty function doesn't access nor modify the state.